# How to configure unpluged NICs on Hyper-V Server

Tags: networking, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I am installing a new host server based on Hyper-V server. Currently it has a network cable plugged-in and four more free network interfaces (including one ILO). When I start the server and reach the blue command line screen, I can just configure IP for the pluged interfaces. As this machine is intended to be configured off-site and moved to final location, I cannot plug all connectors right now, but need the different IPs configured prior to moving.

My question is how (if any) can I access the configuration options for unplugged network interfaces?.

Thanks in advance,

Jose.

Comment: You should be able to powershell this - Type `Get-NetAdapter` does it list all (exept the ilo) the NICs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using command line:

First of all, list all the interfaces and **note their names**:

```
netsh interface ipv4 show config
```

Then configure each interface as following:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="YOUR INTERFACE NAME" static IP_ADDRESS SUBNET_MASK GATEWAY
```

Example:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Wi-Fi" static 192.168.3.8 255.255.255.0 192.168.3.1
```

Or if there is DHCP server on final site:

```
netsh interface ip4 set address name=”YOUR INTERFACE NAME” source=dhcp
```

Most probably you will need to set up DNS server too:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="YOUR INTERFACE NAME" static DNS_SERVER
```

Example:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="Wi-Fi" static 8.8.8.8
netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="Wi-Fi" static 8.8.4.4 index=2
```

### Using PowerShell:

Get the list of interfaces and **note their names**:

```
Get-NetIPAddress | ft InterfaceAlias
```

Example how to set or change the IP address:

```
New-NetIPAddress –InterfaceAlias “Wired Ethernet Connection” –IPv4Address “192.168.0.1” –PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway 192.168.0.254
```

and DNS

```
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias “Wired Ethernet Connection” -ServerAddresses 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2
```

Hope it helps.